# Deleting the Uncategorized Category

Tags: wordpress

I like to categorize all my posts. Is there a way that I can delete this category ? If not Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete the "Uncategorized" category:

1. Use the category dashboard under **Posts > Categories** to create a second category (if you haven't already)
2. Select a new default category on the **Settings > Writing** panel
3. Return to **Posts > Categories** and use the checkboxes & drop-down menus to delete "Uncategorized"

You can also just edit the "Uncategorized" category's name and slug. I changed mine to "Miscellaneous" (`/category/misc/`).

Answer (score 2):

You need a default category (perhaps with different name) because that's where the posts go when you delete a different category. There is a need for some sort of 'none of the others' place.

The question is, why do you care? Are you saying that you don't want to **display** that empty category? Then look for plugins that hide a specific category instead.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Wordpress does not display empty categories. Just make sure you have no post in the "uncategorized" category, and it won't appear on the front end